# Collection2 autoValue on client: Access Denied

Tags: meteor, schema

When defining a autoValue on the server, it works just fine:

```
slug: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    unique: true,
    autoValue: function () {
        var title = this.field("title");

        if (Meteor.isServer && title.isSet)
            return Helpers.slugify(title.value);
    }
}
```

However if I want to run define the autoValue on the client too, like this:

```
slug: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    unique: true,
    autoValue: function () {
        var title = this.field("title");

        if (title.isSet)
            return Helpers.slugify(title.value);
    }
}
```

There is an Access Denied whenever I update the documents title.

However for the `updated_at` field, it works for both, server and client:

```
updated_at: {
    type: Date,
    autoValue: function() {
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I cannot `autoValue` the slug on the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I just had a `.deny()` on update. Removing that fixed it.